# Is it possible to get a timestamp in the VS source control window?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015 is it possible to get a timestamp included for each line when a file is updated? So for instance:

> 2016-06-28 10:30:45.106 Replacing....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools has an option to do this ([VS2013 version](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace), [VS2015 version](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)) called "Timestamp margin".

From their site:

[image]

It also has many, many other features. You can turn each feature off separately though, so if you don't want the other features you can turn them all off.

Comment: That is for the DEBUG window. Does not seem to affect the SOURCE CONTROL window though unfortunately ;-(